# Proving that ∀xG(x,a)⊢∃xG(a,x)

Tags: natural-deduction

Can I prove ∀xG(x,a)⊢∃xG(a,x) this way:

```
∀xG(x,a)   premise
G(a,a)     ∀xe
∃xG(a,x)   ∃xi
```

Comment: Seesm OK to me. Why the doubt?

Comment: Because G(a,a) is the result of applying x = a to G(x,a).

Comment: That's a valid rule AFAIK.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, you can prove it that way.

Here is another way. The tableau
$$
\forall x G(x, a) \\
\lnot \exists x G(a, x) \\
G(a, a) \\
\lnot G(a, a)
$$ is closed, so the result holds. (It's a proof by contradiction.)

Comment: So in both G(x,a) and G(a,x) you then have to substitute x = a for the proof by contradiction to work?

Comment: Yes: $\lnot \exists x G(a, x)$ is the same as $\forall x\lnot G(a, x)$. What I've done is take $\forall x G(x, a)$ as a premise then assume $\lnot \exists x G(a, x)$.

Answer (score 2):

Your proof is correct. I think you are doubting yourself because in going from $G(a,a)$, is it ok to not replace all $a$'s with $x$'s? This is a common concern.

But yes, this is indeed ok!

In general:

When you *eliminate* a quantifier, then you *do* need to replace all variables that were quantified by that quantifier using a constant.

But when you *introduce* a quantifier, you do *not* have to replace all constants that you quantify by the variable you use for that quantifier.